Intersection of two ideals, <p(x)> and <q(x)> where p(x),q(x) are in a PID R[x]
I was guessing that <p(x)> intersection <q(x)> to be the ideal<LCM(p(x),q(x)>. But I couldn't proceed. Please help me to complete the proof if my intuition is correct. Otherwise give a counterexample, if possible.Also does this hold on any UFD(ofcourse,if holds here) , cause we have gcd and LCM in any UFD , I guess.

If $a\in\langle p\rangle$ and $a\in\langle q\rangle$, what can you say about $a$?

a|p and a|q i.e a|LCM (p,q) . Can you please tell me how to use the mathematical signs ( e.g. you have used "belongs to". I am a beginner here.

and then you get...?

okay I have got the intersection is subset of <LCM (p,q)>

I can complete now . Thanks for helping.

Hey Souvik! Welcome to MSE. If you'd like to learn more about formatting math symbols, you can start here: [ https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation ].
